# Jquery scroll to offset target div always

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset

I have added a new sticky menu and I want the secondary sub-menu (that has an offset on load) to stay offset when scrolling.

Im a bit of a n00b and Im not getting it.

I am using this link as reference:
[Jquery scroll to offset target div on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525293/jquery-scroll-to-offset-target-div-on-page-load/56567799#56567799)

```
    // Goddamn scroll-to links

    // Get offset height depending on our sweet ass screen width
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            var theOffset = 16;
        } else if ( $(this).is(':first')) {
           //var offset = $('.entry-header').height()  + 30;
        } else {
            var theOffset = $('.subheader').height() + 30;
    }

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        //$('.subheader li').removeClass('active');
        //$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
            || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: (target.offset().top - theOffset)
                }, 500);
                return false;
            }

        }

    });

and this:

if(window.location.hash) {
         $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top-theOffset
      }, 900, 'swing');
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/a/52834225/2321594?  Javascript has its own `scrollIntoView` for Elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView